# "From to" or "From Through"

Tags: word-choice

Which is correct: "I got the chance to work there as an employee FROM 2013 TO 2014 or FROM 2013 THROUGH 2014"? Or does it depend on whether you worked there for the whole of 2014?

Answer (score 4):

"To 2014" can suggest a stopping point in 2014.

"Through 2014" suggests a stopping point at the end of 2014.

"Into 2014" suggests a stopping point somewhere within 2014.

Other different ideas:

"Into 2014", means stopping in the first half of 2014.

"Through most of 2014" means stopping in the second half of 2014.

Answer (score 0):

In English, that's just a weird way to phrase it.

"I worked from March 2013 to April 2014" is more reasonable.  That's  just an example.

I worked at X from Y March 2013, until Z April 2014" is better.

"I left because Z" helps.

Z can be a good or bad or maybe indifferent thing!  Think about what you'd say.

For your specific question, give specific monthly dates for your period.  NB, I'm answering in English.  No offence - if you considering should give a non-Engish answer, consider how to translate them

[Maybe patronising - but better safe than sorry - I picked example month dates!  Translate as you decide fit

Comment: "I'm answering in English. No offence" - None taken. This is an English-language site, so answers are *expected* to be in English. Though I think your point is that your answer is only applicable to the English language, not necessarily other languages?